# Scorm 1.2 is not supported in Chamilo with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scorm, unity-webgl, lms, chamilo-lms

I am a student trainee and my company wants to use chamilo to publish language courses using Scorm. Indeed, it uses Unity software to develop a course application.
I used the GitHub project Unity-SCORM-Integration-Kit to generate a zip file of a test project that I want to import on Chamilo.

I succeeded to publish this project with webGL on the LMS chamilo but it contains some errors.
first of all, it shows me below the application:

> > ***Initialize *** SCORM 1.2 not currently supported

then, in the learner data section, when I insert the learner preferences fields, I get this error:

> > NullReferenceException: Object in the element inspector. (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

The test project is present in this link: https://github.com/rstals/Unity-SCORM-Integration-Kit.

a demostration of this project is avalable in this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GydMMoBR1Ek&t=672s&ab_channel=TechnologyToolkit

I use Unity 2019.4.19f1

how to fix this problem ?

[screeshot of the chamilo LMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/copoN.png)

I thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Are you using the [`Unity-SCORM-Integration-Kit-WebGL.unitypackage`](https://github.com/rstals/Unity-SCORM-Integration-Kit/blob/master/Unity-SCORM-Integration-Kit-WebGL.unitypackage)?

Comment: yes i use this package.